# Samba sharing asking for username and password only on VPN Windows Clients

Tags: debian, openvpn, samba

I have a SAMBA share that works exactly as expected on the local network. There is a folder that needs authentication to access and a public folder that is accessed without authentication.

The problem happens when I'm at home and I'm connected through the VPN that I created on a server in the company where I work. When trying to access the share  ***\\ip*** , a Windows screen is displayed asking for the user and password before the folders are displayed.
In the case of the local network, as mentioned earlier, everything goes as expected. When accessing the share, the folders are displayed before asking for a user and password.

[user and pass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmNX0.png)

I looked at the log and couldn't find any error regarding this access. Believe that there may be some global configuration in my smb.conf file.

In the internal network with a configuration below, a "Files" folder is available without authentication while "scripts" asks for a password.

```
[global]
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    max log size = 1000
    syslog = 0
    panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
    usershare allow guests = Yes
    map to guest = Bad User
    obey pam restrictions = Yes
    pam password change = Yes
    passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
    passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
    server role = standalone server
    unix password sync = Yes
    dns proxy = No
    idmap config * : backend = tdb

[Arquivos]
    comment = Arquivos de Usuarios
    path = /media/root/ARQ USUA/Arquivos/
    guest ok = Yes
    guest only = Yes
    read only = No
[Scripts]
    comment = Scripts de Execucao
    path = /home/scripts/
    read only = No
    valid users = fulano
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be redacted in English.

Comment: Sorry, can you point the rule where it says that i cannot post in my native language? I couldn't find it. If it's against the rule I rewrite the topic.

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8162). Personally I am all for non-English questions, but it is better if you translate it, if you wish to get a good answer.

Comment: That's a good point. Thank you.

Comment: Could you please clarify if you are using a machine that works fine in the office, or this machine is a home machine that has never accessed this share?

Comment: now I'm using a machine in my home that has never accessed the share. When the credencials are prompted and I put the user and password I can get the access to the share but what I want is the same behavior from my workplace that is access the share without windows prompting for credencials.